# Ошибка too many redirects

Tags: веб-программирование, .htaccess, redirect, dns, cloudflare

Пытаюсь поставить форум (invision community) на сайт forum.nextx.ru. DNS у cloudflare. При заходе на полностью нулёвый сайт (без форума) возникает ошибка `too many redirects`.

Если отключить PHP (пробовал со всеми доступными версиями от 5.6 до 8.1), то ошибка исчезает.

При записи в .htaccess `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]` с включённым php то ошибка опять исчезает, но если поставить форум, то снова появляется.

В корневом каталоге хостинга есть файл .htaccess c таким содержанием:

```
# Редирект с http на https создан автоматически при заказе бесплатного ssl-сертификата
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
# Конец редиректа
```

PS. Сейчас сайт пустой и с записью в .htaccess `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас наверняка стоит Off или Flexible режим. При этом режиме Cloudflare делает запросы к вашему серверу по http, а вы его редиректите на https. Так получается цикличный редирект.

Используйте Full или Full strict режимы. Full strict только в том случае, если на сервере валидный сертификат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]